# Checking Positivity

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

This is my matrix:

```
H = {{2*a1*p4, -p5*a2, p3*a1, 0},{-p5*a2, 2*a2*w1, -p2, -p1},{p3*a1, -p2, 2*a3*w2, 0},{0, -p1*a4, 0, 2*a4*w3}}
```

Where a1,a2,a3,a4 are non-negative constants and the rest are parameters also being non-negative. I want to check positivity of the (4,4) element of the inverse matrix. After computing the inverse element I have used the following code:

```
assumptions = And @@ Thread[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, w1, w2, w3} >0];

result = Assuming[assumptions, Reduce[d > 0, Variables[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, w1, w2, w3}]]]
```

Here, d is the (4,4) element of the inverse matrix. Is my code ok?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code in InputForm so that we can copy and paste it into a notebook.

Comment: Edited. Can you please check now?

Comment: You write d>0 but d is not defined. Did you mean H>0?

Comment: d is the (4,4) element of the inverse matrix of H.